# Выбор элемента при парсинге (cURL)

Tags: php, curl, парсер

Здравствуйте. Есть следующий код:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'S');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Как выбрать, например, див с классом 'name', кто знает? Желательно, без использования библиотек, либо с phpQuery. Ну, если по-другому нельзя, то давайте с библиотеками. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Я пробовал с помощью phpQuery это сделать, но не получилось:

```
require 'phpQuery.php';
$text = curl_exec($ch);
phpQuery::newDocument($text);
    $new_text = pq('.name');
    echo $new_text;
phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
```

Comment: а phpQuery это не библиотека? где ваши попытки это сделать-то?

Comment: @teran, мои попытки тщетны. смысл их выкладывать и путать людей?

Comment: там две строки кода нужно для этих целей (в phpQuery). одна чтобы создать документ, вторая чтобы выбрать див.

Comment: @teran, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Что насчет SimpleHTMLDom?

Comment: @erm, с этой библиотекой не работал, но, если вы знаете решение - давайте

Comment: дак вы документ в переменную сохраните `$html = phpQuery::newDocument($text)`, и с ней работайте `$d = $html->find("div.name")` и `echo pq($d)->text()`

Comment: В интернете полно примеров ее использования. Она достанет `div` с любым классом. Вам только нужно обратиться к поисковым системам :)

Comment: @erm по phpQuery тоже примеров не мало, просто кому то ленно читать и разбираться

Comment: @teran, дело в том, что в `$text` ничего не записывается, из-за этого парсится весь контент на странице и он же показывается, после `$text = curl_exec($ch);` код игнорируется

Comment: @rebber по адресу `http://example.com/` нет дива с классом __name__

Comment: @Эдуард, это домен для примера...

Comment: @rebber приведите реальный пример, чтобы можно было реально показать код.

Comment: @Эдуард, https://www.fl.ru/tu/53279/perenos-sayta-s-joomla-na-wordpress.html, заголовок (Перенос сайта с joomla на wordpress)

Comment: @Эдуард ну что?

Comment: @rebber позже зайду с ПК, напишу пример.

Comment: @rebber https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688726/185343

Comment: @rebber ну что?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием регулярных выражений, но если искать нужно несколько вхождений по разным параметрам, то возможно вам удобнее будет воспользоваться подходящей для этих целей библиотекой

```
<?php

$url = 'fl.ru/tu/53279/perenos-sayta-s-joomla-na-wordpress.html';
preg_match_all('~<h1[^>]*>([\w\s]+)</h1>~iu', curl($url), $arr);

echo $arr[1][0]; // Перенос сайта с joomla на wordpress


function curl($url) {
    $ua = strip_tags($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $ua,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1
    ];
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```